# How to create a service with an API?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I'm pretty new at .NET world so this question might seem a bit basic for you.

I would like to have a service that will run some code once a day (As far as I understood, it can be done by using timer in a microsoft service) and also can be accessed from websites of mine, using some kind of api.

Can this be done in microsoft services? How it can be done?

Comment: You can do it using Task Scheduler or Windows Services

Comment: What is Task Scheduler?

Comment: Check [this](https://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/)

Comment: My daily task will be processing and outputing data for my web application to display, how can I make this task scheduler initiate only once and not every time a user accesses the web application? and how can I make the web application to access the data the task outputs?

Comment: Task scheduler will not work if you want it to be continuously accessed by a website.

Answer (score 0):

Break this task up into 2 applications.

1. A console app that gets triggered by the task scheduler. (You can also use a windows serviceif you wish)
2. A web service possible web api or a wcf service depending on your requirement to access the data.